# How can I have a dynamically changing menu in a single QMainWindow, multiple nested QWidgets application on Symbian Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

My application consists of one QMainWindow, and a nested QStackWidget containing the rest of the application "forms".

I would like to have a soft-key activated menu on each of those sub forms.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi sabbour here is the [link](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-use-qstackedwidget-in-qt.html),which gives you a detailed info, perhaps this could be very useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Multiple widgets and associated menu items, when you load the widget in stack, you need to load your menu items accordingly in the mainwindow menu bar. Note your menu bar is constant and only menu items will be getting changed.